# golang slice variables in a datastore.NewQuery() Filter specification?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm slicing a comma delimited string with `strings.Split()` and am able to extract the desired sub-slice.

```
friends := string("9q4kq,9q47y,9q4kp,9q4kj,9q4km,9q47v,9q4kr,9q47z")
s := strings.Split(friends, ",")
f0:= s[0]
```

`datastore.NewQuery()` chokes (no records returned) when I specify the Filter component of `datastore.NewQuery()` using the slice `f0`:

```
Filter("Field1 =", f0)
```

same result using

```
Filter("Field1 =", string(f0))
```

However, when I hardcode the Filter component, I get the desired records:

```
Filter("Field1 =", "9q4kq")
```

What is the the right way to refer to these slices in the Filter ?

Please see http://play.golang.org/p/DxPAgq3H28.

Answer (score 0):

I did a global find and replace of `f0` with `randomLowerCaseVar` and the darn thing works.

It seems to me that `f0` is a legit identifier [http://golang.org/ref/spec] and not reserved in any way.

> > What is the the right way to refer to these slices in the Filter ?

I think the answer is "use a string variable not named `f0` "

By the way, `F0` also works as a string variable name.